# error compilation, function pointer

Tags: c, compiler-errors

i have a simple program like this :

```
#include<stdio.h>

void add(int *nb)
{
    *nb += 1;
}

int f(int nb, void (*add)(int *))
{
    if (nb < 5)
        f(nb, add(&nb));
    return (nb);
}

int main() {
    int b = 5;
    int a = f(b, add);
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

i want to call f recursively until nb become greater or equal to 5, but when i compile the program , the gcc compiler show something like this :

```
error: passing 'void' to parameter of incompatible type 'void (*)(int *)'
```

can anyone help me please?

Comment: You need to pass a function pointer in to your function call as an argument.  instead, you are attempting to call a function and pass the results in as an argument.

Comment: probably because your function `add` returns `void` instead of `void*`

Comment: Your question title must be in english, not in french

Comment: ok @Jabberwocky, yes chrisitian , i was doing it wrong, thanks you all.

Comment: @E.Ayman nothing prevents you from [edit]ing your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The line `f(nb, add(&nb));` doesn't make sense. You need to call the function somewhere, but not on the same line as where you pass the function pointer on, recursively.

Overall the program doesn't make much sense. I have no idea what you are trying to do, perhaps something similar to this?

```
#include<stdio.h>

void add(int *nb)
{
    *nb += 1;
}

void f(int* nb, void (*add)(int *))
{
    add(nb);

    if (*nb < 5)
    {
        f(nb, add);
    }
}

int main() {
    int a = 5;
    f(&a, add);
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

Will print 6 since the `add` is called once. The name `add` as function parameter to `f` is also mighty confusing, so better come up with another name for it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not completely certain as to what you are trying to do with your function, but I took a stab at what I think you might be attempting to do:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void add(int *nb)
{
    *nb += 1;
}

int f(int nb, void (*function)(int *))
{
    function(&nb);
    if (nb < 5)
        f(nb, function);
    return (nb);
}

int main() {
    int b = 5;
    int a = f(b, add);
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

Now your function `f` accepts a function-pointer to a void function that takes an `int *` as an argument (I renamed this argument to `function` so it doesn't conflict with your existing function `add`).  It proceeds to call said function and pass in a pointer to `nb` to `function`.

What you were doing was passing in the result of `add(&nb)` into the function `f` as an argument (which said function is a void so it does not return anything) instead of passing in a pointer to the function.

Answer (score 0):

Passing `add(&nb)` as an argument passes the *returned value* of `add` with the argument `&nb`. The function signature for `f` requires a function pointer, which can be passed as:

```
f(nb, add)
```

Also, even if you were actually trying to pass the returned value of `add`, that would be undefined behavior since it is of type `void`.

Answer (score 0):

As Christian pointed out in the comments, the problem is on the recursive call line:

```
 f(nb, add(&nb));
```

If I understand correctly you are trying to increase `nb` using the function you receive as a pointer; here however you first pass `nb` unchanged (and as a value, not by reference), and then call the add function.

In the second argument the compiler is expecting a function pointer, but instead it receives the return value of the `add(&nb)` function call, which is `void`.

Also, in case nb is < 5 you need to return the recursive call.

The correct procedure would be:

```
#include<stdio.h>

void add(int *nb)
{
    *nb += 1;
}

int f(int nb, void (*add)(int *))
{
    if (nb < 5) {
        add(&nb);
        return f(nb, add);
    }
    return (nb);
}

int main() {
    int b = 1;
    int a = f(b, add);
    printf("%d\n", a);
}
```

It almost seems like you're trying to use lazy evaluation, but C doesn't have that!